# StaleElementReferenceException in PageFactory in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, testng

I am trying to interact with an element before or after updating it. When I try to interact with an element after updating it, I am getting StaleElementReferenceException.

**Note:-** My simple question is whether we can handle StaleElementReferenceException which is occurred when previous reference of WebElement is deleted permanently.
If it is not possible, I will consider using **By locator instead of WebElement using @FindBy**.

I have tried to handle StaleElementReferenceException using retry mechanism, but still in vain. I have even tried to reinitialize all the elements in that corresponding page, but still in vain. I have recently created my framework with PageFactory.

Can someone please let me know how to handle this situation?

I heard that we cannot handle StaleElementReferenceException in PageFactory. Many people are suggesting to go using **By locator instead of WebElement using @FindBy**.

One of reusable component:-

```
    public void click(WebElement element, int timeout) {
    int attempts = 0;
    while (attempts < 10) {
        try {
            waitUntilElementIsClickable(element, timeout);
            moveToElement(element, timeout);
            element.click();
            break;
        } catch (ElementClickInterceptedException e) {
            log.info("Reperforming click operation since 
           ElementClickInterceptedException is occured");
            if (attempts == 9) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new ElementClickInterceptedException(
                        "Retried clicking 10 times, hence 
   throwing this exception");
            }

        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            log.info("Reperforming click operation since 
     StaleElementReferenceException is occured");
            if (attempts == 9) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new ElementNotInteractableException(
                        "Retried clicking 10 times, hence 
   throwing this exception");
            }
        }
        attempts++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you get it? `PageFactory` just provides a wrapper for the field. Each time you access it it performs lookup from scratch. So there cannot be stale elements.

Comment: @AlexeyR. `Each time you access it it performs lookup from scratch. So there cannot be stale elements.` That is not true. The first time it looks up an element, it looks it up from scratch. Each time after that when the variable is referenced, it uses the existing reference which can easily cause stale elements. This is a major and well documented problem with PageFactory.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JeffC can you provide any link to that well-documented problem? I've always been thinking that the default behavior is to re-lookup unless you apply `@CacheLookup` annotation.

Comment: @AlexeyR.  Added one of the reusable components in the question.

Comment: @AlexeyR. I don't have any links handy but I'm sure some googling will produce some results. What I have is my personal experience years ago running into it on a regular basis before I abandoned PageFactory and also the volume of questions here on SO asking this very same question. Also, I went to SeleniumConf a few years ago and Simon Stewart, the Selenium Project Director, said in his keynote to NOT use PageFactory, at all... https://youtu.be/gyfUpOysIF8?si=vZQGE0b5gMQXp5hw&t=1518.

Comment: @PleasePlease so I am not sure where exactly is `PageFactory` involved in your code example..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you abandon PageFactory for the page object model using locators defined in the page object using `By`. Then in your methods, fetch the element fresh each time using the defined locator.

A simple example of a login page page object would be...

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class LoginPage {
    WebDriver driver;
    private final By usernameLocator = By.id("username");
    private final By passwordLocator = By.id("password");
    private final By submitButtonLocator = By.cssSelector("button[type='submit']");

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void login(String username, String password) {
        driver.findElement(usernameLocator).sendKeys(username);
        driver.findElement(passwordLocator).sendKeys(password);
        driver.findElement(submitButtonLocator).click();
    }
}
```

You would call it like

```
String username = "username";
String password = "password";
...
LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
loginPage.login(username, password);
```

Comment: Yup, I am also looking to switch to By locator due to this pathetic StaleElementReferenceException

Comment: @PleasePlease If this or any other answer was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so the question isn't left unanswered.